# Angular reactive file chooser required validation and cancel event

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on reactive forms in Angular material. I have to add the file upload option, so I have added below code for file chooser functionality.

```
 <mat-label style="margin-right:8px;">{{obj.fieldLabel}}: <span *ngIf="obj.required">*</span>
                            </mat-label>
                            <div style="margin-right: 10px;">
                              <input [required]="obj.required" #fileInput hidden type="file" name="file"
                                     onclick="this.value=null"
                                     (change)="getFileEvent($event,obj.fieldName)"/>                    
                              <button mat-flat-button color="primary"
                                      (click)="fileInput.click();chooseFileBtnClick(obj.fieldName)" type="button">
                                Choose a File</button>
                              <mat-error
                                *ngIf="obj.required && this.isFileUploadCancel">This
                                field is required.
                              </mat-error>
                            </div>
```

Events are :

```
public getFileEvent(event: HTMLInputEvent, fieldName) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      this.fileMap.set(fieldName, file);
      this.fileUploadMap.set(fieldName, file.name);
      this.isFileUploadCancel = false;
    }
    else {
      alert("cancel event may be, but it will not work as without choosing file you can not enter in change event");
    }
    this.objectFormGroup.controls[fieldName].setValue(file ? file.name : '');
    return null;
  }
```

Click event, but this is also not working as it get called before change and flag do not work properly and message displayed on just choose button click, which is not correct way :

```
  public chooseFileBtnClick(fieldName: string) {
    if (this.fileUploadMap.get(fieldName) === undefined) {
      this.isFileUploadCancel = true;
    }
  }
```

I need to show validation message that 'This is required field.'

I have tried many things but :

- There is no direct way to detect cancel event, I have tried adding another events, but not worked. If I get cancel click to work so that I can know that no file chosen and user cancel selecting file.
- Added in change event and set the validation. but not worked.

How can I proper show the validation if user do not choose file and if it is made required.

Comment: did you try putting `formControlName="yourControlName"`in your input?

And in your `getFileEvent` you will pass your `formControlName` in your 2nd parameter

Comment: If I add formControlName then it throw compile error : error TS2339: Property 'fileInput' does not exist on type 'MyFormComponent'. File input working fine, inly thing I need to show the validation, otherwise functionality is fine. Second parameter have the name of the control and it works.